# How to store for loop result and refer in a command?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have a for loop like below,

```
values="addressSearchBaseUrl addressSearchSubscriptionKey cacheUrl calendarApiUrl checkoutBffApiUrl cpCode"

for ptr in $values
do
echo $ptr
temp=$(az pipelines variable-group list --group-name "${target_backend}"|jq '.[0].variables.'${ptr}'.value')
echo $temp
echo $?
done
```

Now, I want each result to be referred in the command below:

```
az pipelines variable-group variable create true  --name "Sales.Configuration.Spa ${new_env}" --variable "addressSearchBaseUrl" --value "${parse or store the value from above loop}" "addressSearchSubscriptionKey" "--value "${parse or store the value from above loop}"...
```

can anyone kindly assist me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a few newlines can really help with the readability of your code.

Take advantage of shell arrays:

```sh
values=(
    addressSearchBaseUrl
    addressSearchSubscriptionKey
    cacheUrl
    calendarApiUrl
    checkoutBffApiUrl
    cpCode
)
az_create_options=()

for ptr in "${values[@]}"
do
    result=$(
        az pipelines variable-group list --group-name "${target_backend}" \
        | jq ".[0].variables.${ptr}.value"
    )
    printf "%s\t%s\t%d\n" "$ptr" "$result" $?

    # add the variable and value to the array
    az_create_options+=( --variable "$ptr" --value "$result" )
done

# inspect the create options, if you want
declare -p az_create_options

# now, create them
az pipelines variable-group variable create true  \
    --name "Sales.Configuration.Spa ${new_env}" \
    "${az_create_options[@]}"
```

Comment: Curious - why use `\ ` rather than just put the pipe at the end? (OP does specify `bash`)

Comment: I like having the pipes at the front: to me it's more obvious that the 2nd command is in a pipeline vs hiding the pipe at the end of the 1st command. Partially inspired by [Google shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#pipelines)

Comment: Fair. I tend to put the pipe at the end and intend the next command on the following line, mostly because I like to keep a running column of comments on the RHS to help me (and anyone else that ends up maintaining it) figure out what it's doing six months later.  Thanks for the link, will read through it.

Comment: @glennjackman Can you kindly assist me with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920818/issue-with-single-quotes-running-azure-cli-command